# Get tooltips data from python?

Tags: python

I am writing an addon popup that shows all the current shortcuts. This is context sensitive and I have it mostly done. However, I am not able to get much information from the other python addons.

Below is some of CoDEManX's code that collects a lot of the info I need.
However, it does not seem to collect anything for Python addons.

Is there a way to collect the same info that the tooltips do from within python?

```
mod, opname = idname.split(".")
idname_c = "{!s}_OT_{!s}".format(mod.upper(), opname)
idtype = getattr(bpy.types, idname_c)
description = idtype.bl_rna.description
```

Comment: You might try `idtype.__doc__` to get the documentation string.

Comment: I am unsure from which information you want to derive what.So do you have the idnames of the operators or do you want to get them ? if you have the idnames then what exactly do you want to get from the operators ?

Comment: The tool tip. ie a description of what the op does.

Comment: thanks pink vertex that got a few more but there are still dome to go. It is very helpful I will be able to follow that lead a bit more.

Comment: The code is here (http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=332167&d=1410283515) If you try it you'll see what's missing.

Comment: i still do not understand what your intital data is. i mean, do you have the operator at hand, or its bl_idname, or do you need a way to find all operators of a specific addon, or do you need a way to find all addons first ? when you already have the idname of your operator then i do not understand what the problem is with the code above as it already solves your problem... So i must clearly not get what you want.

Comment: CoDEManX's code works for many of the operators. However it doesn't work for all and it doesn't return the """tooltip""" info this is the standard way that python addons seem to store the description of the function. I can find no way to get the info in the """tooltip""" of each op as the tooltips do.

Comment: Just to be a little more clear the above code works fine for the internal stuff but addons seem to return an empty string. The tool I have built list the shortcuts and what they do so I need a description from every op. This is not the case. As far as I can see so far the C code collects the """tooltip""" header info to create the tooltips however these don't seem to be available through python. What I am wondering is, Is this the case or can I access the info and how do I find where it is. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Also the __doc__ returns stuff when description doesn't but the shortcuts/ops in say the node wrangler return an empty string. So even though I have the shortcut I can't show what it does (apart from showing what op it calls and what arguments it assigns).

Comment: I'll stick to this comment line and reply to the answers after some more exploration. This is what I did last night after pink vertex's input 
`idtype = getattr(bpy.types, idname_c)
description = idtype.bl_rna.description + ". "
if idtype.__doc__ is not None:
    description += "idtype.__doc__ " + idtype.__doc__
` This occasionally adds the __doc__ information but not always. I am going to track this down. Everyone's input has been fantastic help. Thanks HEAPS

Comment: Sorry about the code I can't get the hang of the textarea input here

Comment: Thanks for the edit CoDEmanX my English is lazy. I usually try a bit harder with my code though.

Answer (score 2):

Wow Blender/Python is really like an onion ( a rather large on at that ) and my eyes have been watering like made getting through the layers :)

Ok I finally ran grep in the scripts directory as I should have when pink vertex first sugessted it. Duh.
Line 340 in bl_extract_messages.py gives it up (code below). So it looks to me that if it doesn't have a bl_rna.description (or bl_description) then it uses the `__doc__` part. 
In the process I realised that the bulk of what I need is directly in the keymaps them selves as .name attribute of the individual keymap. This is derived from the bl_label that is in the op that is called by the new keymap definition line.

So I went round in circles when it was right under my nose.
Thanks again everyone.

```
    if bl_rna.description:
        process_msg(msgs, default_context, bl_rna.description, msgsrc, reports, check_ctxt_rna_tip, settings)
    elif cls.__doc__:  # XXX Some classes (like KeyingSetInfo subclasses) have void description... :(
        process_msg(msgs, default_context, cls.__doc__, msgsrc, reports, check_ctxt_rna_tip, settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips appear to display the `__doc__` string from the operator class. The simple operator template also hints that this is the tooltip.

There is nothing in place to force an operator to have a `__doc__` string so you may want to fall back to the `bl_label` which must be defined. In the rare event that is an empty string I would fall back to the idname.

```
mod, opname = idname.split(".")
idname_c = "{!s}_OT_{!s}".format(mod.upper(), opname)
idtype = getattr(bpy.types, idname_c)

if len(idtype.__doc__) > 0:
    description = idtype.__doc__
else:
    if len(idtype.bl_label) > 0:
        description = idtype.bl_label
    else:
        description = " ".join(opname.split("_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the operator's bl_idname at hand. Lets say your operator's bl_idname is "avastar.shape_type_bone_hint"

Now you can do this:

```
# I assume you got the operator's bl_idname from somewhere.

idname = "avastar.shape_type_bone_hint"
op = eval("bpy.ops."+idname)
idtype=getattr(bpy.types, op.idname())

# Now you can get the operator's bl_* declarations as follows:

bl_idname      = getattr(idtype,"bl_idname",      None)
bl_label       = getattr(idtype,"bl_label",       None)
bl_description = getattr(idtype,"bl_description", None)
bl_options     = getattr(idtype,"bl_options",     None)
```

I am still unsure if this is exactly what you have asked for. but this will give you the operator's bl_description. However, maybe there is a more elegant way to get the idtype from the operator.